# How do we create sub-directories in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to copy folders and nested folders (sub-directories) from Google Cloud Storage to [Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) and retain the hierarchy in Big Query. But only appending of data happens in Big Query and no sub-folders get created. How do I do that?

Comment: see also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905752

Comment: Would be a great feature

Answer (score 5):

BigQuery doesn't have the concept of sub-folders. You have datasets and tables underneath those datasets. That's all.